# .NET passing client certificate from API to API in HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, client-certificates

I have a problem with passing a certificate with HTTP request from API to API.

Here is the path:

1. I make an HTTP request to 1st API from Postman. I grab the certificate from this requests.
2. In 1st API I configure HTTP client to use this certificate and make a call to 2nd API.

Here is the code example:

```
[HttpPut(Name = "CertPassing")]
public async Task Put(int val)
{
    var certificate = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;

    using (var httpClient = CreateHttpClient(certificate))
    {
        using (var httpMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://uri"))
        {
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpMessage);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}

private static HttpClient CreateHttpClient(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler
    {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
        CheckCertificateRevocationList = false,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true
    };
    
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;

    return new HttpClient(handler);
}
```

2nd API doesn't receive this certificate. 2nd API is also behind Azure API Management and I have an operation policy which check if certificate is null or not.

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null)">
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="403" reason="Certificate missing" />
                </return-response>
            </when>
        </choose>
        <set-backend-service id="apim-generated-policy" backend-id="func" />
        <set-header name="Thumbprint" exists-action="override">
            <value>@(context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint)</value>
        </set-header>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

I always got 403 in response when I do a call from API to API. When I do a direct call to 2nd API from Postman with the same certificate it's working fine.

I am using .NET Core 2.1 and I cannot update it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So after further investigation I found out that's not possible in my case. The problem is that when I receive a certififcate in 1st API it's doesn't have private key included. In that case I cannot use it as client certifcate and pass it to 2nd API.